# Array manipulation based on inner object property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am working with the wordpressAPI to retrieve information and display it in a javascript application. I would like to know the proper way to manipulate an array based on the data in the returned objects. For example:

Data I get back is an array containing 3 objects:

```
data = [{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

The objects contain data like:

```
{ id: 1234, slug: 'slug-name', status: 'published' }
```

..and much more. But what I would like to know is how to loop over each object and check for slug === 'slug-name-2' and if it is, I want to take that whole object with all of its information and move it to the beginning of the data array.

Comment: Look into [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in many different ways, one way would be to "pseudo-sort" the array on the given key and value:

```js
const input = [
  { id: 1234, slug: 'slug-name-0', status: 'published' },  
  { id: 1234, slug: 'slug-name-1', status: 'published' },
  { id: 1234, slug: 'slug-name-2', status: 'published' },
  { id: 1234, slug: 'slug-name-3', status: 'published' },
  { id: 1234, slug: 'slug-name-4', status: 'published' }
]

const output = input.sort((a, b) => {
  if (b.slug === 'slug-name-2') return 1;
  return 0;
})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it

```
//find index of the slug-name-2
let index = data.findIndex((x => x.slug === 'slug-name-2');
//get object
let slug = data[index];
//remove from current location
data.splice(index)
//add it to the beginning
data.unshift(slug);
```

I'm sure one can come up with 100 more ways and perhaps more efficient ones.

Look at the [Array.Prototype methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype), there's so many out there, you can use a combination of few and manipulate array in so many ways.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You could [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it based on the slug string.

```js
let data = [
  { id: 1234, slug: 'slug-name', status: 'published' },
  { id: 1235, slug: 'slug-name-1', status: 'published' },
  { id: 1236, slug: 'slug-name-2', status: 'published' },
  { id: 9999, slug: 'slug-name-2', status: 'published' },
  { id: 1237, slug: 'hello', status: 'published' }
];

let sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => b.slug.indexOf('slug-name-2') - a.slug.indexOf('slug-name-2'));
console.log(sortedData);
```